# PHP just pushing the first variable to push notification in Android

Tags: php, android, android-studio

I have created an android app utilizing WebView and have integrated FCM in it to send push notifications, I am using a MYSQL database to store my tokens and using php script to send push notification. The script is just sending the first variable and not the second which contains the url to the image,
Here is the FirebaseMessagingService.java

```
package com.science.s11;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService{

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String message=(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        String image=(remoteMessage.getData().get("image"));
        showNotification(message,image);
    }


    private void showNotification(String message, String image) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        if ((image != null) && (!image.equals(""))) {
            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(image);
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("science")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.s11_noti)
                    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(message))
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setStyle(new Notification.BigPictureStyle()
                            .bigPicture(bitmap)
                            .setSummaryText(message))
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            manager.notify(0,builder.build());
        }else{
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle("science19")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.s19_noti)
                    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(message))
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            manager.notify(0,builder.build());
        }

    }
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String strURL) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strURL);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And the push_notification.php

```
<?php 

    function send_notification ($tokens, $message, $image)
    {
        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $fields = array(
             'registration_ids' => $tokens,
             'data' => $message,
             'image'=> $image
            );

        $headers = array(
                'Authorization:key = ****************** ',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
            );

       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
       $result = curl_exec($ch);           
       if ($result === FALSE) {
           die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
       }
       curl_close($ch);
       return $result;
    }


    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fcm");

    $sql = " Select Token From users";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $tokens = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $tokens[] = $row["Token"];
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

    $message = array("message" => " FCM PUSH NOTIFICATION TEST MESSAGE");
    $image=array("image" => "http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-logo-1200x630.jpg");
    $message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message, $image);
    echo $message_status;



 ?>
```

Whenever I run the push_notification.php, the message gets sent but no the image, the image data is null in the client side. The thing I have found is, if I replace the order of $message and $image in this line,

`$message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message, $image);`
and make it look like this
`$message_status = send_notification($tokens, $image,$message);`

the image gets sent but not the message. So, it seems just the first variable is being passed, but why? can you guys please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
        $fields = array(
             'registration_ids' => $tokens,
             'data' => array(
                 'message'=>$message,
                 'image'=> $image
             )
            );
...
```

But, you should change you notification processor on android side.

Comment: Am confused? What will this pass? like what will it send to android device? $data or $message and $image?

Comment: I can't help in Android side becouse I work only with backend, but I now GCM notification format it should consist device registration ID and data array. In your version you send only string. Now you shoult get array with message and image fields. Sorry, but i'm can't help more with Android side. =)

Answer (score 0):

JSON needs to be treated differently.

```
$data = array("name" => "Bob", "age" => "46");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('http://foo.com/REST/users');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

See http://lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl.